# Ripple Effect on Android pre-L

Tags: android, libraries, ripple

I'm searching for a lib that is able to simulate the new shiny ripple effect when tapping on a button introduced 28th Android L / API 21.
There are already a few apps that use it, like TV Series and Pushtime, for example.. But the libraries I found both do something different (I'm talking about Ripple by traex and Ripple Background).

Thanks a lot guys! See you..

Comment: I think someone posted a RippleView to GitHub a while back, haven't tried it but you might wanna take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/) has every library that I know of that attempts to backport the ripple effect. Here is a list of all RippleEffect libraries: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/167

Answer (score 3):

You must try this, its quite simple [RippleEffect](http://androidfreakstuff.blogspot.in/2015/09/ripple-effect-in-android-for.html)